# Pyspark: Create an array of struct from another array of struct

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm using Pyspark 2.4 and would like to create `df_2` from `df_1`:

**df_1:**

```
root
 |-- request: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- address: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- street: string (nullable  = false)
 |    |    |-- postcode: string (nullable  = false)
```

**df_2:**

```
root
 |-- request: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- address: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- street: string (nullable  = false)
```

I know UDF is one way, but are there any other ways, like the use of `map()`, to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) function :

```
df_2 = df_1.withColumn("request", expr("transform(request, x -> struct(x.street) as address)"))
```

For each element of `request` array, we select only `street` field and create a new struct.

Comment: AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'struct(namedlambdavariable().`street `)' due to data type mismatch: Only foldable string expressions are allowed to appear at odd position, got: NamePlaceholder;